Kotlin default value for non-null field in data class, then dont pass that attribute in json?
I have a data class :
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable
@Serdeable.Deserializable
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class PublishRequest(
    val product: String,
    val env: String = "")

I assumed this means that I can send a json like :
{
    "product": "product2"  }

and env would be set to ""
But I get :

io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 2230ms. Server
Running: http://localhost:8080/v1
22:23:56.761 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR
i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: Parameter
specified as non-null is null: method
com.imaginelearning.ctk.publishing.dto.PublishArtifactRequest.,
parameter label java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as
non-null is null: method x.y.z.., parameter env at
x.y.z.PublishRequest.

I dont want to make env as nullable. Want it to have a value passed by used or my default. Anyway to do that? Using Java 21, micronautVersion=4.4.2
jvmVersion=2
kotlinVersion=1.9.23
If I pass :
{ "product": "product2",
    "env" : ""  } 

it works.
Update:
I tried :
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.17.+"

Made a factory :
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Bean
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory
import jakarta.inject.Singleton


@Factory
class ObjectMapperFactory {

    @Singleton
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        val module = KotlinModule.Builder().build()
        return ObjectMapper().registerModule(module)
    }
}

But no difference. In https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin it talks about older versions of Kotlin, not sure if if that is the issue?

Does this answer your question? How do you make Jackson use Kotlin default params for missing values?

In https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin it talks about older versions of Kotlin, not sure if if that is the issue? @alext

I just tried executing a very similar piece of code in plain Kotlin and had no issues. Are you sure Micronaut is using your object mapper instance and not a default one that's not properly configured?

the issue was that this was project had a parent build.gradle and that has a kotlin plugin that was older than what i wanted. once i fixed that it started working without https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin - worked on its own

This works out of the box in kotlin with :
micronautVersion=4.5.0
jvmVersion=21
kotlin version 1.9
All that I needed to change was update the versions in the parent build.gradle to the ones :
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.24"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.9.24"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.24-1.0.20"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "4.4.0"
    id("io.micronaut.aot") version "4.4.0"
    id('org.openapi.generator') version "5.4.0"
    id 'maven-publish'
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.8.1"
    id 'jacoco'
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.sel2in.kotlinDefaultsJson"

ext {
    awsSDKVersion = '2.17.261'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//TBD TODO later. whether we need this?
//sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs += "${project.buildDir}/generated/openapi/src/main/java"
dependencies {
    ksp("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    ksp("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")
    ksp("io.micronaut.validation:micronaut-validation-processor")

    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")

    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")

    implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")
    //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    compileOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")

    //implementation("io.micronaut.validation:micronaut-validation")
    //implementation("jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.0")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    //runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-management")
    implementation("io.micronaut.micrometer:micronaut-micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")

    implementation 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.6.14'
//    implementation 'org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.6'
//    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
//    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
//    implementation 'io.gsonfire:gson-fire:1.9.0'
//    implementation 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.6.9'
//    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0'
//    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.12.0'
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http")
    //implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject")

//    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-aws-sdk-v2")
//    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb-enhanced:${awsSDKVersion}")

    runtimeOnly("org.yaml:snakeyaml")

    //testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.11.0-M2'
    //testRuntimeOnly 'io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5:4.3.0'


    ///testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.11.0-M2'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(21)
}


subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover")
    kover {

        filters {
            classes {
                excludes += listOf("*di.*", "*Factory*")
            }
            annotations {
                excludes += listOf("*Generated", "*CustomAnnotationToExclude")
            }
        }
        htmlReport {
            onCheck.set(true)
        }
        verify {
            rule {
                isEnabled = true
                name = "Line Coverage of Tests must be more than 80%"
                bound {
                    minValue = 75
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

application {
    mainClass = "com.sel2in.kotlinDefaultsJson.App"
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("21")
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.11" // specify the version of JaCoCo you want to use
}
//
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
    reports {
        xml.required = false
        csv.required = true
        html.required = true
    }
}

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
}

graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.sel2in.kotlinDefaultsJson.*")
    }
    aot {
        // Please review carefully the optimizations enabled below
        // Check https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aot/latest/guide/ for more details
        optimizeServiceLoading = false
        convertYamlToJava = false
        precomputeOperations = true
        cacheEnvironment = true
        optimizeClassLoading = true
        deduceEnvironment = true
        optimizeNetty = true
        replaceLogbackXml = true
    }
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
    finalizedBy 'jacocoTestReport'
 }

tasks.named("dockerfileNative") {
    jdkVersion = "21"
}


tasks.withType(Tar.class).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

tasks.withType(Tar).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}

tasks.withType(Jar).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}

tasks.withType(Zip).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}


tasks.register('writeBuildInfo') {
    doLast {
        def branch = ""
        def log = ""
        try {
            def currentDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now()
            //git not installed on build system so not working
            branch = 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
            log = 'git log --pretty=format:"%h - %s, %cd - %an" -n 11'.execute().text.trim()
            def infoFile = new File("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/generated/info.txt")
            //
            def info = "Build: date-time-timezone: ${currentDateTime}.\n\nGit info, branch: ${branch}.\n\nLog:\n${log}\n"
            infoFile.write(info)
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {

        }
    }
}

tasks.named('compileKotlin') {
    dependsOn 'writeBuildInfo'
}

Command to run :
  gradlew   clean test  koverHtmlReport 

Full test project can see at https://github.com/tgkprog/kotlinIgnoreDataClassPropsDefaultValJson
